# Curry Function in Swift

Tags: swift, currying

I want to make a function that return a curry function like below

```
func addTwoNumbers(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

addTwoNumbers(4)(b: 6) // Result: 10

var add4 = addTwoNumbers(4)
add4(b: 10) // returns 14
```

What is the return type of such function and how can I generate a function like this using a function that take Variadic parameters.

```
func generateCurry(.../*Variadic parameters*/) -> .../*curry function type*/ {
  return ...//curry function
}
```

I want a generic solution and not take only Int as arguments in the parmeter of the generateCurry function

```
let curried = curry(func(a, b, c) {
  print(a + b + c)
})
curried(1)(2)(3) //prints 6
```

Comment: Hi, so what you want to do is: a function that takes another function as parameter and within that function being able to infer which function to call based on type? In addition, your `curried` now prints 6, but what would you like to do when it is of type let say `String`?

Comment: You can have any type but the point is to evaluate the block of code passed in the curry function only after all the arguments have been passed. I have updated the question to show an example using addTwoNumbers method

Comment: I find this article http://www.russbishop.net/swift-function-currying to be extremely useful and well explained

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this pretty easily with closures:

```
/// Takes a binary function and returns a curried version
func curry<A,B,C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C {
    return { a in { b in f(a, b) } }
}

curry(+)(5)(6) // => 11

let add: Int -> Int -> Int = curry(+)
add(5)(6) // => 11
```

It would be really nice to be able to do the same thing for functions that take 3, 4 or more arguments, but without duplicating the implementation. The signature of such a function might start something like:

```
/// Take a function accepting N arguments and return a curried version
func curry<T>(args: T...) -> /* ? */
```

What would the return type be? It would change based on the input to the function. This definitely isn't possible in Swift at the moment, and I don't think it would be possible at all without some kind of macro system. But even with macros I don't think the compiler would be satisfied unless it knew the length of the list at compile-time.

Having said that, it's really straight-forward to manually overload the currying function with a version that accepts 3, 4, 5 or more parameters:

```
func curry<A,B,C,D>(f: (A, B, C) -> D) -> A -> B -> C -> D {
    return { a in { b in { c in f(a,b,c) } } }
}

func curry<A,B,C,D,E>(f: (A, B, C, D) -> E) -> A -> B -> C -> D -> E {
    return { a in { b in { c in { d in f(a,b,c,d) } } } }
}

// etc.
```

Comment: It's possible now  (10 years later )

Comment: @Roman how?! :-D I mean I've seen the proposal for the variadic generic parameters, but I haven't seen how to write a curry function using that new feature of generics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is actually going to be possible in the same way it is inside of languages like Python.

The core problem I see to having a single generic solution is the strong typing of the closures/funcs you want to accept.

You could fairly easily create a curry function that worked on a specific or common function signature, but as far as a general purpose curry I don't see a way for it to work.  The issue is more than about the types of the arguments (as mentioned in comments) but also with the number of them.

I've written up a simple example of how you could implement a curry function.  It works, but I don't see a sane way to have a truly generic one like you can in more loosely typed languages.

```
func add(a1: Int, a2: Int) -> Int {
    return a1 + a2
}

func curry(argument: Int, block: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int -> Int{
    func curried(arg: Int) -> Int {
        return block(argument, arg)
    }

    return curried
}

curry(5, add)(6)
```

Comment: We can use generics and make sure all arguments passed are of type T

Comment: You still run into the fact that a function with different numbers of arguments is a different signature, and thus a different type.  The varadic requirement is part of the problem.

Comment: If we can solve the issue of passing an array in a Variadic function then we can solve this issue. Is there a way in the language to call Variadic method like performSelector in Objective C or can we bridge to Objective C to make it work?

Comment: In swift the variadic implementation appears to effectively be an array.  I did just try to implement a version of my example that uses Any to some effect.  I was able to crash Xcode using it and got a truly impressive compiler error by doing `var test: Any = curry(5,add)`.  I'm keep getting back to a generic curry being impossible in swift, or minimally way more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to quickly get the `curry` function for any number of parameters, it's possible to generate it as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/werediver/9318762f34c1316f242fcba7e43e37e2).

The code is in Swift 2.2 and generates code for Swift 2.2 (at the moment). It uses simple template-based approach (a possible alternative is constructing an AST followed by code-generation):

```
func genCurry(n: Int, indent: Indent = .fourSpaces, accessLevel: AccessLevel = .Default, verbose: Bool = false) -> String {

    // ...
    // The bulky park is skipped for clarity.

    return accessLevel.asPrefix + "func curry<\(genericParams)>(f: \(fSig)) -> \(curriedSig(n)) {\n"
        + indent.single + "return \(closure)\n"
        + "}\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that currying was removed back in Swift3. I created my own version which is repetitive but does the job.

```swift
precedencegroup CurryPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence
}
infix operator <<== :CurryPrecedence
//1 param
func <<==<A,Z>(_ f: @escaping (A) -> (Z), _ p:A) -> () -> (Z)  {
    { f(p) }
}
//2 param
func <<==<A,B,Z>(_ f: @escaping (A, B) -> (Z), _ p:B) -> (A) -> (Z)  {
    { (A) in f(A,p) }
}
//3 param
func <<==<A,B,C,Z>(_ f: @escaping (A, B, C) -> (Z), _ p:C) -> (A, B) -> (Z)  {
    { (A, B) in f(A,B,p) }
}
//4 param
func <<==<A,B,C,D,Z>(_ f: @escaping (A, B, C, D) -> (Z), _ p:D) -> (A, B, C) -> (Z)  {
    { (A, B, C) in f(A,B,C,p) }
}
```

To use it:

```swift
let ten = (addTwoNumbers <<== 6 <<== 4)()
```

or

```swift
let ten = (addTwoNumbers <<== 6)(4)
```