# How to write a flip method in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to write a flip method in Swift.

Here is the signature.

`Prelude> :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`

My code in Swift:

```
func flip1<A, B, C>(f: A->B->C) -> (B->A->C) {

    return { (valueB: B, valueA: A) in
        return f(valueA, valueB)
    }
}

func flip2<A, B, C>(f: A->B->C) -> (B->A->C) {

    return { (valueB: B) in
        return { (valueA: A) in
            return f(valueA)(valueB)
        }
    }
}
```

The `flip1` method can not compile. There is an error `Extra argument in call` at line `return f(valueA, valueB)`

The `flip2` method works fine, except the flipped method can only be called like this `method(1)(2)`.

How to write the `flip` method so that I can use the flipped method like `method(1, 2)` and `method(1)(2)`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Writing cryptic code that doesn't work isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: @gnasher729 The method flip(f) return a new method which has the arguments of f in reverse order.

Comment: I believe your method signature for `f` is missing parenthesis around the `A->B`.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh So what is the difference between (A, B) and A->B?

Comment: @sablib: `(A, B)` is a *tuple* and `A->B` is a function (or closure) mapping A to B.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Got my Haskell mixed up with my Swift. It should be as Martin has it below, with the comma. But the parenthesis are necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A->B->C` is the type of a function taking one argument of type `A`
and returning a function `B->C` (a "curried" function). The type of a function taking
two arguments is `(A, B)->C`:

```
func flip<A, B, C>(f: (A, B)->C) -> (B, A)->C {

    return { (valueB: B, valueA: A) in
        return f(valueA, valueB)
    }
}

let x = flip(-)(10, 5)
println(x) // -5
```

It can slightly be shortened to

```
func flip<A, B, C>(f: (A, B)->C) -> (B, A)->C {

    return { (valueB, valueA) in
        f(valueA, valueB)
    }
}
```

due to automatic type inference.

As far as I know, Swift does not automatically convert functions
taking multiple arguments into curried functions, compare
[Typecase regular Swift function to Curry Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824338/typecase-regular-swift-function-to-curry-function).

Answer (score 0):

This is the @MartinR answer updated to Swift 5.1

```
func flip<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping (A, B)->C) -> (B, A)->C {

    return { (valueB: B, valueA: A) in
        return f(valueA, valueB)
    }
}
```

> let x = flip(-)(10, 5) println(x) // -5

It can slightly be shortened to

```
func flip<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping (A, B)->C) -> (B, A)->C {

    { (valueB: B, valueA: A) in
        f(valueA, valueB)
    }
}
```