# Is there a way to reference instance function when calling SequenceType.forEach?

Tags: ios, swift

Consider type `Foo`:

```
class Foo {

    var isBaz: Bool {
        return false
    }

    func bar() {
        print("some boring print")
    }
}
```

Now let's say I want to iterate through a collection of class instances and call some function on each of them:

```
let someFoos: [Foo] = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]

someFoos.forEach { $0.bar() }
```

This syntax is quite compact, but it feels a bit awkward. Also, it cannot be used everywhere. For example, in an `if` statement condition:

```
if someFoos.contains { $0.isBaz } { 
    // compiler error: statement cannot begin with a closure expression
}

if someFoos.contains($0.isBaz) { 
    // compiler error: anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure
}

if someFoos.contains({ $0.isBaz }) { 
    // this is correct, but requires extra pair of parentheses
}
```

Ideally, it would be nice to write something like

```
someFoos.forEach(Foo.bar)
```

but as of Swift 2.1 this is not a correct syntax. Such way of referencing the function would be similar to the following:

```
func bar2(foo: Foo) -> Void {
    print("some boring print")
}

someFoos.forEach(bar2)
```

Is there a better way to reference instance function? How do you prefer to write such expressions?

Comment: Unclear what on the problem is. What on earth is not to like about `someFoos.forEach { $0.bar() }`? Also unclear what your `if` constructs are intended to accomplish.

Comment: @matt `someFoos.forEach { $0.bar() }` is fine, but IMO something like `someFoos.forEach(Foo.bar)` would be better (easier to read). 
`if` statements are just to illustrate that in some cases additional parentheses are needed to use `someFoos.forEach { $0.bar() }` syntax, which makes code less readable.

Comment: You're not really answering the question. "IMO" is not a question, and Stack Overflow rejects opinion-based questions. What problem are you having? And seriously, what behavior are you hoping from from those `if` examples? Maybe there's another way if you would just say what you want the code to _do_.

Comment: @matt if `bar()` was not a function of `Foo`, it would be possible to reference it as `someFoos.forEach(bar)`. I am asking if there is a way to reference function of the class in a similar way. Apparently there isn't, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @deville can show code where `someFoos.forEach(anythingFromFoo)` will work?

Comment: @deville But you answered your own question. `bar()` _is_ an instance method of Foo.

Comment: @matt maybe he is trying to tell us something with his `print()`

Comment: @RMenke god forbid :)

Comment: Instance methods are curried functions which take the instance as the first parameter. So `someFoos.forEach { Foo.bar($0)() }` compiles and works. – Your "desired" `someFoos.forEach(Foo.bar)` is identical to `someFoos.forEach { Foo.bar($0) }` which is different and does not compile

Comment: I think you have mixed two questions in one: #1: How to use instance methods as curried functions in a closure, and #2: Why does the trailing closure syntax not work in an if-statement. – Perhaps you should separate those questions.

Comment: @MartinR that's interesting, I didn't know that, thanks! `someFoos.forEach { Foo.bar($0)() }` is not really more readable than `someFoos.forEach { $0.bar() }`, but it's nice to know it can be done.
Also, I will consider reformulating my question to avoid mixing two questions in one.

Comment: @deville: Yes, that was not meant as a "more readable" version but only to clarify why `someFoos.forEach(Foo.bar)` does not work as you perhaps expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two different problems here. The *trailing closure syntax*
can be used when calling a function and the last parameter is a closure,
so

```
let b1 = someFoos.contains({ $0.isBaz })
let b2 = someFoos.contains { $0.isBaz }
```

are fully equivalent. However, the trailing closure syntax can be problematic in the condition of an if-statement:

```
if someFoos.contains({ $0.isBaz }) { }  // OK
if someFoos.contains { $0.isBaz } { }   // Compiler error
if (someFoos.contains { $0.isBaz }) { } // OK, as noted by R Menke
```

We can only speculate why the second one does not work. It could be that the compiler 
takes the first `{`  as the start of the if-body. Perhaps this will
change in a future version of Swift but  probably it is not worth
the effort.

---

The other problem is about *curried functions*.

```
someFoos.forEach(bar2)
```

compiles because `bar2` has the type `Foo -> Void`, and that is exactly
what the `forEach()` method expects. `Foo.bar`, on the other hand,
is a curried function (see http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) which takes the instance as the first
argument. It has the type `Foo -> () -> ()`. So

```
Foo.bar(someFoo)
```

is a closure with type `() -> ()`, and

```
Foo.bar(someFoo)()
```

calls the `bar` method on the `someFoo` instance.

(*Note:* The following is not meant as an actual recommendation,
but only as a demonstration about curried functions and fun
with closures!)

To pass `Foo.bar` directly as an argument to `forEach()` we need to
"swap" the order of the parameters. Haskell has a "flip" function for that purpose,
and it is also possible in Swift (see e.g. [How to write a flip method in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593940/how-to-write-a-flip-method-in-swift)):

```
func flip<A, B, C>(f: A -> B ->C) -> B -> A ->C {
    return { b in { a in f(a)(b) } }
}
```

Then `flip(Foo.bar)` has the type `() -> Foo -> ()`, so
the void argument of the `bar` method can be applied

```
flip(Foo.bar)()
```

to get a `Foo -> ()` closure, and

```
flip(Foo.bar)()(someFoo)
```

calls the `bar` method on the `someFoo` instance.
And now we can call

```
someFoos.forEach (flip(Foo.bar)())
```

without using a closure expression `{ .. }` !!

If `isBaz` were a *method* instead of a property

```
func isBaz() -> Bool { return false }
```

then you 
could do the same in the if-expression:

```
if someFoos.contains(flip(Foo.isBaz)()) { 
    // ...
}
```

Again, this is only meant as a demonstration. Also *properties*
are not curried functions, so this cannot be done with
your `isBaz` property.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such an exhaustive answer! A lot of food for thought!

Answer (score 0):

The `$0` syntax is there to help you create a shortcut, but if you don't like it you can use the more complete form:

```
someFoos.forEach { thisFoo in thisFoo.bar() }
```

Comment: My book outlines how anonymous functions may be abbreviated in Swift: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions You don't have to use _any_ of the abbreviations if you don't want to.