# Calling instance method on each object in array

Tags: swift

Let's assume this situation: I have an array of objects and I want call instance method on each one of them. I can do something like that:

```
//items is an array of objects with instanceMethod() available
items.forEach { $0.instanceMethod() }
```

The same situation is with `map`. For example I want to map each object to something else with `mappingInstanceMethod` which returns value:

```
let mappedItems = items.map { $0.mappingInstanceMethod() }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do that?

For example in Java one can do:

```
items.forEach(Item::instanceMethod);
```

instead of

```
items.forEach((item) -> { item.instanceMethod(); });
```

Is similiar syntax available in Swift?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you are doing in

```
items.forEach { $0.instanceMethod() }
let mappedItems = items.map { $0.mappingInstanceMethod() }
```

is a clean and Swifty way. As explained in [Is there a way to reference instance function when calling SequenceType.forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049116/is-there-a-way-to-reference-instance-function-when-calling-sequencetype-foreach), the first statement cannot be reduced
to

```
items.forEach(Item.instanceMethod)
```

There is one exception though: It works with `init` methods
which take a single argument. Example:

```
let ints = [1, 2, 3]
let strings = ints.map(String.init)
print(strings) // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    for item in items {
        item.instanceMethod()
    }
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have been more specific. I want closure syntax which can be also used in `map` function for example.

Comment: Question is, why would you prefer a closure syntax. Closures are great, and very handy at times - but there's a price to pay. In debugging - they are "unnamed" and hard to trace-back. Only use them when you want to, say, receive  a closure from the outside (as input to your function) and apply it to each element, things like that. For simpler scenarios - use simpler semantics. It'll also help the readers of your code.

Comment: What if instanceMethod is a mutating function in struct?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
let mappedItems = items.map { $0.mappingInstanceMethod() }
```

note the `()` to call the method

Edit 1:

sample code:

```
class SomeObject {

    func someFunction() -> Int {
        return 5
    }
}

let array = [SomeObject(), SomeObject(), SomeObject()]

let ints = array.map { $0.someFunction()}
print(ints)
```

Comment: It was just a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: I know that it works, I was just looking for other syntax for this. As @MartinR pointed out in his comments, this is the 'swiftiest' way to do this and there is no shorter way available.