# Swift, use function UIView.removeFromSuperview as an argument in forEach function over array of views

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I would like to change following code

```
    let views: [UIView] = []
    views.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

to some other way, in which I pass function `UIView.removeFromSuperview` as an argument to the forEach function. 
Something similar to

```
        let views: [UIView] = []
        views.map {  /* transform views to be passed further */ }
            .forEach(UIView.removeFromSuperview)
```

Is it possible somehow?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer below and some comments, I can sum up feedback for this question for myself a bit.

1. [Instance Methods are “Curried” Functions in Swift (By Ole Begemann)](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)
2. [Flattening the function type of unapplied method references (Swift Evolution)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md)

Based on the latter, Chris Lattner has mentioned some `flip` function in a paragraph *Impact on existing code*.

My assumption about its implementation is something following

```
func flip<T>(_ function: @escaping (T) -> () -> Void) -> (T) -> Void {
    return { object in function(object)() }
}
```

Thus, we can rewrite initial code like

```
views.forEach(flip(UIView.removeFromSuperview))
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049116/is-there-a-way-to-reference-instance-function-when-calling-sequencetype-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to just call the method on `$0`:

```
views.forEach {
    $0.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

(And you can name the argument if you like.)

But you could also wrap it into a method:

```
extension Sequence {
    func onEach(_ invoke: (Iterator.Element) -> () -> Void) {
        self.forEach { invoke($0)() }
    }
}
```

This works because [instance methods can be represented as functions that take an instance of their type](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) and return a function that has their "top-level" signature.

One downside here is that you can't include the `rethrows` annotation that's present on `forEach`, because `rethrows` only applies if the function argument itself is throwing.

Comment: You don't need the extra `-> Void` for `invoke`'s type, right? Why not just `(Iterator.Element) -> ()` and call it as `invoke($0)`?

Comment: You do, because the return type of the first function is not Void, it's another function. Calling `invoke` just produces that function; then you still need to invoke _it_.

Comment: @Connor Read the article Josh linked to at the bottom of this answer

Comment: @Connor: Here's [a gist that might make it clearer what's happening](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5f8a5ffe63ff388c6658890f99c9812c).

Comment: Note to future readers: [SE-0042](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md) passed, which when implemented, will change instance methods from being curried like `(Instance) -> (Arg1, Arg2, ...) -> ReturnType` to being `(Instance, Arg1, Arg2, ...) -> ReturnType`, similar to how `self` is passed in Python. When this change is implemented, `array.forEach(Class.instanceMethod)` will be possible, given that `instanceMethod` takes no arguments (besides the implicit `self` parameter)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks