# How to use a swift Instance method with flatMap?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, flatmap

I can define a global function which doubles up strings:

```
func double(string: String) -> [String] {
  return [string, string]
}
```

And now can use this with flatMap

```
let animals = ["Ant", "Bear", "Cat"]
print( animals.flatMap(double) ) // ["Ant", "Ant", "Bear", "Bear", "Cat", "Cat"]
```

But we don't like Globals ;-)
So I extend string instead:

```
extension String {
  func double() -> [String] {
    return [self, self]
  }
}
```

But I can't use that in the same way as I get:

```
print( animals.flatMap(String.double) ) // [(Function), (Function), (Function)]
```

I can see that the issue is that the types are different.

```
print("type(of: double) = \(type(of: double))") //type(of: double) = (String) -> Array<String>
print("type(of: String.double) = \(type(of: String.double))") //type(of: String.double) = (String) -> () -> Array<String>
```

I can see that String.double is not of the right type for the flatMap and this is emphasised by the warning message I get:

> 'flatMap' is deprecated: Please use compactMap(_:) for the case where
>   closure returns an optional value

I think this is because the compiler is not finding a suitable overload for flatMap.

How can I use the instance method with flatMap in the same way as I did with the global function?

Comment: `print( animals.flatMap { $0.double() } )`

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy.  I did originally have $0.double() but I loved the simplicity of ".flatMap(double)" so was hoping to keep away from $0

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to reference instance function when calling SequenceType.forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049116/is-there-a-way-to-reference-instance-function-when-calling-sequencetype-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With instance method, you cannot.

Instance method is a curry method, the type `(String) -> () -> Array<String>` mean "a method take string and return a function which takes nothing and return array of string".

So you can do like this, but not as you write.

```
print(animals.flatMap{ String.double($0)() }) // ["Ant", "Ant", "Bear", "Bear", "Cat", "Cat"]
```

What you need is a static method. It simply take string and return array of string.

```
extension String {
    static func double(_ string: String) -> [String] {
        return [string, string]
    }
}

print(animals.flatMap(String.double)) // ["Ant", "Ant", "Bear", "Bear", "Cat", "Cat"]
```

Comment: Nice @taka - neat.  And if I don;t want to mess with my instance method I can do: extension String {
  static func double(_ string: String) -> [String] {
    return string.double()
  }
} and then follow your example.  Thanks.