# Why is n-arity currying not possible in Swift?

Tags: swift

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25375190/1102215) currying in Swift with an arbitrary number of parameters isn't possible. I'm trying to understand why. Consider this code, which in my head seems like it should work:

```
func addArray (numbers: [Int]) -> ((Int...) -> Any) {
    return { (nums: Int...) in 
        (nums.count > 0) ? addArray(numbers+nums) : numbers.reduce(0, combine: +)  }
}

func add (numbers: Int...) -> ((Int...) -> Any) {
    return addArray(numbers)
}
```

- **[Interactive REPL](http://swiftstub.com/605628660/?v=gm)** 
  <-- btw, that's swift v1. [Here's the same thing with swift v2 beta](http://swiftstub.com/92690282/?v=beta)

#### First Test:

```
println("sum = \(   add(11)()   )")
// => sum = 11
```

so far so good...

#### Second Test:

```
println("sum = \(   add(11)(12)   )")
// => sum = (Function)
```

excellent, now can we call that function?

#### Third test

```
println("sum = \(   add(11)(12)()   )")
// => <stdin>:19:21: error: invalid use of '()' to call a value of 
// => non-function type 'Any'
// =>     println("sum = \( add(11)(12)() )")
// =>     ^ ~~
```

... Huh? Didn't you just say that `add(11)(12)` was a function?

Now it's a **non-function type 'Any'** ?!1!1 wtf?

Note that I was expecting the result to be `sum = 23`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the return type of `Any` (which is the return type of the function returned by `add`). When you print the value of `add(11)(12)` you can see – due to polymorphism – that this time it returned a function type, but as far as the compiler is concerned the type of the return value is still `Any` (and some other time it might return another type for those parameters), which cannot be called.

If you are certain that it will return a function, you can cast it:

```
print("sum = \( (add(11)(12) as! ((Int...) -> Any))() )")
// => sum = 23
```

Note that you have the same problem of type if you try to use the `Int` value:

```
var sum = (add(11)(12) as! ((Int...) -> Any))()
sum += 1 // Error, because `sum` is `Any`
```

So even there you would have to do:

```
var sum = (add(11)(12) as! ((Int...) -> Any))() as! Int
```

Comment: great explanation, but wow, so it's sort of possible but extremely painful.