# Currying func in Swift 4

Tags: swift, functional-programming

In **Swift 4,** how can I curry `func`, or something similar:

```
func doSomething(a: A, b: B, c: C) {
}

let do_a = doSomething(a: value_a)
let do_ab = do_a(b: value_b)
let result = do_ab(c: value_c)
```

In JS, we can do:

```
const sum = x => y => x + y;

// returns a function y => 2 + y
sum (2);

// returns the number 3
sum (2)(1);
```

I read the answer in here 
[Curry Function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107191/curry-function-in-swift)

But I want to ask for the current Swift (Swift 4). And can I avoid to create a generic func?

`func curry<A,B,C,D,E>(f: (A, B, C, D) -> E) -> A -> B -> C -> D -> E`

This post is very useful: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introduction-to-function-currying-in-swift

But it's from 2014

Thank you.

Comment: You mean currying? I think Swift once supported that but removed that feature.

Comment: @Sweeper exactly, thank you. I will edit the question.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm sorry for the unclear question. I want something like currying. doSomething just a sudo code.

Answer (score 3):

You used to be able to do this very easily in Swift 2:

```
func add(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
```

let add3 = add(3)
   let result = add3(b: 5) // 8

[Starting from Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md), this is no longer valid syntax.

You'd have to do something like this:

```
func add(_ a: Int) -> (Int) -> Int {
    return { $0 + a }
}
```

For three parameters, this will be even longer and harder to understand. I recommend you not to do this.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I know that. That why I ask this question. How to curry for every func without the long trail. I'm not sure we can achieve it in Swift 4.

Comment: Swift 3 and up actually lets you write `func add(_ a: Int) -> (Int) -> Int`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Do you mean I should remove the brackets? I originally added them for clarity.

Comment: @anhtu Look at the duplicate. It shows a `curry` function that curries a function.

Comment: @Sweeper thank for your help. But I think we can't do more than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107191/curry-function-in-swift

Comment: @Sweeper `(A) -> (B) -> (C) -> D` is a lot more readable than `(A) -> ((B) -> ((C) -> D))` :)

Comment: @TimVermeulen Okay, edited.