# Currying func and keep param name/ label in Swift 4

Tags: swift, functional-programming, currying

In Swift 4, how can I curry func, and keep param label/ name:

```
func doSomething(a: A, b: B, c: C) {
}

let do_a = doSomething(a: value_a) // keep name a
let do_ab = do_a(b: value_b) // keep name b
let result = do_ab(c: value_c) // keep name c
```

With the answer from here [Curry Function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107191/curry-function-in-swift)

And https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introduction-to-function-currying-in-swift

I can do, but the label is omitted

```
let curryDo = curry(doSomething)
let doA = curryDo(value_a) // but the a label is removed here.
```

How to keep param label/name in currying func?

Answer (score 1):

Swift removed currying as a feature in version 3, and all current implementations use closures, which don't have labeled arguments.

Comment: Thank you. Still waiting for a solution. T_T

Comment: @anhtu, Propose re-introducing currying on Swift Evolution.  If no one steps up, nothing will happen.