# Static method wrapper for map in Swift

Tags: swift, static, set, mapping

Every method in Swift has correspondent static function generated by Swift automatically.
But I'm having hard times to apply this concept for `map`.
For example. This is a canonical way of doing things:

```
let numbers = Set([1, 2, 3])
let doubled = numbers.map { $0 * 2 }
print(doubled) // [2, 4, 6]
```

What I want is to make the following code compile and work (because in theory it should compile and work just like the code above):

```
let numbers = Set([1, 2, 3])
let doubled = Set.map(numbers) { $0 * 2 }
print(doubled) // [2, 4, 6]
```

P.S. By the way, how is this feature called officially?

Comment: Do you mean this? – [Instance Methods are “Curried” Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the fact that an instance method like this:

```
class C {
    func foo(x: T1, y: T2) -> R { ... }
}
```

can also be called as if it were a static method like this:

```
class C {
    static func foo(`self`: C) -> (T1, T2) -> R { ... }
}
```

This is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), but only on the first parameter. Usually currying `foo` (above) would mean `func foo() -> (C) -> (T1) -> (T2) -> R`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25375190/5133585

You can use the static version of `map` like this:

```
let numbers = Set([1, 2, 3])
let doubled = try Set.map(numbers)() { $0 * 2 }
print(doubled)
```

Note that the extra `()` after `map(numbers)`. Without it, the parser would think that the closure is an argument for the `Set.map` call. The `()` is needed to make it clear that the closure is an argument for the *function returned by* `map`. You can also not use the trailing closure syntax:

```
try Set.map(numbers)({ $0 * 2 })
```

You also need `try`, because `map` is declared with `rethrows`:

```
func map<T>(_ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

Normally, `rethrows` means that if `transform` doesn't throw, `map` also doesn't throw. But since the static version of `map` only takes a `Set` and returns a `((Self.Element) throws -> T) -> [T]`, it cannot know whether the closure you are going to pass throws or not. Therefore, it stays on the safe side and assume it will throw.